# How can a query return 'yes' if a matching record exists and 'no' if not? SQL / MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have the following tables:

**Student Data**

- Student ID (primary key)

**Prior Education**

- Student ID (foreign key)
- Prior Education Code

At the moment I have a query that displays various data from **Student Data** with one record per student. I want to add an additional column to this query that shows "Y" if there is at least one matching record in **Prior Education** and "N" is there is no matching record. Basically I want an answer to the question "Does this student have any prior education?".

I want one record per student in the query regardless of how many records they have in **Prior Education**.

I'm working in MS Access and have little experience with SQL so solutions that don't require much SQL knowledge are preferable, but not necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use `LEFT JOIN` and `IIF`.

```
SELECT student.studentid,iif (isnull(prior.priorid),'Yes','No')
FROM student LEFT JOIN [prior] ON student.studentid = prior.studentid;
```

EDIT:

```
SELECT student.studentid, iif(count(prior.priorid)<>0,'Yes','No')
FROM student LEFT JOIN [prior] ON student.studentid=prior.studentid
group by student.studentid
```

Comment: This does exactly what I asked for, however it gives multiple records per student based on the number of records they have in **Prior Education**. I should've been more specific in my original question (I've since edited it to fix this). If you could modify the code to achieve this that would great.

Comment: @LittleJohn - Add group by and compare value of Count() aggr function. Have a look at edited post.